# Integral definition of Bessel function is equivalent to power series representation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, power-series, bessel-functions

Let $$J_n(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(z\sin(t)-nt)\mathrm{d}t$$ be the $n$-th Bessel function. I need to prove that this definition is equivalent to $$J_n(z)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m+n)!}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n+2m}$$
I have noticed that both satisfy the equation $z^2J_n''(z)+zJ_n'(z)+(z^2-n^2)J_n(z)=0$, but the result does not follow from this alone.

Comment: Its not hard to show that the only solutions to Bessel's equation that behave like $z^{n}$ around $0$ are multiplies of $J_{n}$. Then you just have to check the exact constants.

Comment: @pax could you please elaborate? I still don't see how one would prove this kind of uniqueness.

Comment: Check that they and their respective derivatives agree at $z=0$.